# Digital Mixer implementation for DDC/DUC

Tags: signal-processing, interpolation, software-defined-radio

I am trying to implement digital up/down converter in which the implementation flow is

DUC
Interpolation->Digital mixer

DDC
Digital mixer->Decimation

In DUC digital mixer the input is I AND Q symbols then same I,Q are recoverd at DDC digital mixer
I wnat to find out complete equations of Mixer so that i can easily implement it

According to my understanding in DUC digital mixer the equation is
Transmit_signal=I*Cos(wt)-Qsin(wt);

And in the receiver side the I and Q is recovered through following sequence

Reciver_I=Transmit_signal*Cos(wt);
Reciver_Q=Transmit_signal*sin(wt);

Reciver_I_fil=lowpassfilter(Reciver_I);
Reciver_Q_fil=lowpassfilter(Reciver_Q);

but i cannot be able to recover the exact I and Q symobls at the receiver side please help to find the exact equations

Comment: Is there a phase offset present in your received signal?

Comment: No phase and frequency mismatch is present in the signal

Comment: How is recovered signal different?